# Regex for Excluding special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing regex to match address, which have characters, spaces in between alphabets, comma, numbers, letters like Ö , œ, â etc.

I want to write regex for address which match with all characters except these(Ö , œ, â) in perl

I wrote

```
qr/.{1,100}/i
```

but it matches with all characters including these characters, I just want to match address that don't have special characters.

Comment: you mean this `qr/[a-z0-9,\s]{1,100}/i` ?

Comment: it also have other characters like -, _ , ` etc. I cant predict what are the characters coming for that field. I just want to remove special characters and accept all other

Comment: `I cant predict what are the characters coming for that field` when you cant how can regex do that?

Comment: How can I know which address user will give? I just want to remove special characters from address field - that is my requirment

Comment: `Ô œ â ...` are **not** special, they are letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to match the ASCII character set

```
/\p{ascii}+/
```

And if you want to check whether a string contains any non-ASCII characters then you can use the inverse of the *property* class above

```
print "String okay" unless /\P{ascii}/
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a white list of characters by using

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/
```

or a blacklist by using

```
/^[^öäü]*$/
```

The first `^` matches the start of the string, the second one is a `not` for the characters.
The `$` matches the end of the string.

I'd suggest using a white list, since you probably know the characters you can deal with, but you might not know all characters you can not deal with.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried in javascript. 
It's working perfectly in java script,you can convert it into perl.

here is code

> /^[A-Za-z0-9() -]*$/

This is allowing ASCII Characters and spaces,but not allowing special characters in any where.

```
Example:-
sdddd -- allowing
@xxx123 -- not allow
abcdfe4 -- allow
123 ba xx -- allow
pqrs_    -- Not allow
```

Comment: But you are rejecting anything that contains punctuation marks. Incidentally, why do you have `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+` which is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}`?